# Molar extinction coefficient a measure of the probability of a photon of the associated wavelength being absorbed?

Tags: spectroscopy

Obviously the molar extinction coefficient is not equal to the probability of a photon of the associated wavelength being absorbed, but is it a measure of the probability i.e. the higher the value of the molar extinction coefficient, the higher the probability of absorption of the photon per molecule?